# Django/PIL Error - Caught an exception while rendering: The _imagingft C module is not installed

Tags: python, django, macos, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to run a webapp/site on my machine, it's running on OSX 10.6.2 and I'm having some problems:

```
Caught an exeption while rending: The _imagingft C module is not installed
```

Doing import _imagingft in python gives me this:

```
>>> import _imagingft
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/PIL/_imagingft.so,
2): Symbol not found: _FT_Done_Face
 Referenced from: /Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/PIL/_imagingft.so
 Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/PIL/_imagingft.so
```

It's seems that the Freetype library is the one having problems. No errors so far when installing PIL or when I compiled(?) the jpeg and freetype libraries so far.

I'm on django 1.1.1, python 2.6.2.

Comment: how did you install PIL?

Comment: I got the same error running PIL 1.1.7 for Python 2.6 on XP. If no solution worked try PIL 1.1.6 instead.

Comment: @Dmitry
Using sudo python setup.py install

Comment: If it helps, here's a console dump when i'm installing PIL:

http://drop.io/kenokb4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've had this problem as well. Couldn't resolve it with PIL 1.1.6 nor with PIL 1.1.7. I installed py26-pil from ports and presto, it works.

```
sudo port install py26-pil
```

If you don't have ports, go to http://www.macports.org/

Answer (score 9):

Before (re)installing PIL add the following sysmlinks to enable freetype on Mac 10.6 Snow Leopard:

```
ln -s /usr/X11/include/freetype2 /usr/local/include/
ln -s /usr/X11/include/ft2build.h /usr/local/include/
ln -s /usr/X11/lib/libfreetype.6.dylib /usr/local/lib/
ln -s /usr/X11/lib/libfreetype.6.dylib /usr/local/lib/libfreetype.dylib
```

Comment: It looks like the files already existing in /usr/local/lib/ were in i386 while those in /usr/X11/lib/ are in x86-64. So deleting the old ones and symlinking to the new ones does the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution for this.

First you need to download **Freetype2** http://freetype.sourceforge.net/index2.html and compile it with these instructions http://www.libgd.org/DOC_INSTALL_OSX#Building_freetype2 then you go and compile **libjpeg** and **PIL** http://fightingrabbits.com/archives/266

And that's it.

Answer (score 1):

With errors like those it's usually because one of PIL dependencies were not compiled to be universal binary.

Try this:

1. Download the framework for Freetype at [this website](http://www.kyngchaos.com/software:frameworks)
2. Download the package for libjpeg8 at [this website](http://ethan.tira-thompson.org/Mac_OS_X_Ports.html)
3. Remove the files that you originally installed for libjpeg and freetype
4. Install the new packages
5. Delete your build folder for PIL
6. Re-build and install PIL

But if you want to try compiling universal binary first, be my guest.  My specific issue was actually with libjpeg, and no matter how I compiled it, PIL was barfing on `import _imaging`. So I opted for packaged versions. I don't think libjpeg or freetype specifically benefit from compiling them yourself.

libjpeg8 package installs to /usr/local/lib

freetype package installs to your /Library/Frameworks folder.

Answer (score 0):

The environment is not set up correctly to build the OS X PIL\libjpeg binaries using easy_install. This guide should help http://fightingrabbits.com/archives/266 - It's for installing Python/Django but goes through the necessary PIL setup first and works for me on 10.6.x